# Text aligned with link button in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on an app where several times there are text labels combined with buttons or where a part of the text has a different color.

This time, I need to achieve this:
[image]

The "Sign in" text button has to have an action attached to it and also have a different look from the rest of the text.

I have tried with a StackView with the Horizontal attribute but it just depends too much on the width of the device and text length and it doesn't look centered horizontally on the screen.

On Html I would do something like

```
Already have an account? <a>Sign in</a>
```

Is there something like that on XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grid with auto-sized columns and a `TapGestureRecognizer` on the `Sign In` label is one approach that will produce a consistent look on iOS and Android as buttons are not used.

```
<Grid Padding="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Already have an account?" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" />
    <Label x:Name="onSignIn" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Sign In" TextColor="Red" BackgroundColor="White" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

In the code behind:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (sender, e) => D.WriteLine("Tapped");
onSignIn.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - spans. You can build a formatted string using spans that have different fonts, colours, sizes etc.

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <FormattedString.Spans>
                <Span Text="Hello" ForegroundColor="Red" FontAttributes="Italic" FontSize="10" />
                <Span Text="World" ForegroundColor="Blue" FontSize="10" />
            </FormattedString.Spans>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Span text is not bindable, but FormattedText on Label is, so you can build a FormattedString in your view model and bind that to the FormattedText property.

Comment: Bindable Spans are in 3.1.0 and gestures were added to Span in 3.2.0. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this existing solution:
https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/tag/xamarin-hyperlink-label/